# QR Code generator

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>QR code generator</title>
<style>
  body { font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
  section {
    margin: 50px auto;
    max-width: 350px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #size { max-width: 64px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
  <h1>QR code generator</h1>
  <p>Enter an URL or some text bellow and hit the Generate button (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)!</p>
  <textarea id="textarea" autofocus></textarea>
  <label for="size">Size (px):</label>
  <input id="size" type="number" value="150" min="50" max="500" step="50">
  <button onclick="genQRcode()">Generate</button>
  <div id="content" style="display: none;">
    <p><img id="qrcode" src="" /></p>
    <label for="qrcode-url">QR Code URL:</label>
    <input id="qrcode-url" type="text" onclick="this.select()">
  </div>
</section>
<script>
  var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea"),
    content = document.getElementById("content");

  function genQRcode() {
    var data = encodeURIComponent(textarea.value),
      size = document.getElementById("size").value,
      chart = "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=" + size + "x" + size + "&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0&chl=" + data;
    if (data === "") {
      alert("Please enter a valid data!");
      textarea.focus();
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "";
      document.getElementById("qrcode").src = chart;
      document.getElementById("qrcode-url").value = chart;
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
      genQRcode();
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Minor nit: "bellow" => "below". ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This code looks fine to me.

If you are interested in nitpicking then :

- Style information should be in a css file
- JavaScript should be in a js file
- Your image tag should have an alt
- It should show some indication that you are leveraging a Google API ?
- Assigning events like this `<button onclick="genQRcode()">` is obsolete
- `Please enter a valid data` is not proper English ( "Please enter valid data" )
- You should consider adding the listener to the textarea, not the document

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. But why "Please enter a valid data" isn't proper English. can you correct this?
*English isn't my primary language...

Comment: @udd: In English, "data" is plural.  (Well [more or less](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11356/sample-collection-params-vs-samples-collection-params/11357#11357).)  It would probably be better to say what sort of data (URL, free text, etc.) you plan to encode.  Also, you don't really validate the data beyond making sure it's not a zero-length string, so "valid" is a touch misleading.  (But this is all on the nitpicking level.  Well done.)

Comment: @JonEricson, it would be more precise to say that *data* is either plural or uncountable. In modern usage it seems to be [uncountable more often than plural](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/data#Usage_notes).